# Configure apache server to accept same domain post requests

Tags: configuration, apache2

I keep getting 405 errors when i try to send post ajax requests on localhost from a page to another.I understood this is a server configuration.Can anyone help ?

Comment: This should probably be moved to ServerFault

Answer (score 0):

You need a script handler of some kind (python, php, etc.) to handle POST's. The point of a POST is that you are sending data back to the server, without the script handler, apache doesn't know how to do anything with that data.

Comment: i have php. i get the error when sending the data via jQuery